# How to validate a string value that should only return true if numbers are entered

Tags: c#

I need to extend this code to also call the GetReasonForFailure method if anything other than numbers are returned.

I.e

123 = invalid

ABC = invalid

1234567890 = IsValid

NULL = IsValid

```
using System.Linq;
namespace WorksheetValidator.Rules
{
    public class ImportCommodityCode : IRule
    {
     public bool IsValid(string value)
    {
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) || value.Length == 10 ;
    }

    public string GetReasonForFailure(string value)
    {
        return string.Format("[{0}]  Codes should be 10 digits long and only contain numbers", value);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Why are you considering a null string a valid number?

Comment: And why is 123 invalid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Int32.TryParse cannot be used in this context because `9999999999` is bigger than [Int32.MaxValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.maxvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) so it overflows and the conversion fails. 
You could use `long.TryParse` or, if you want an IEnumerable solution, you could write

```
public class ImportCommodityCode : IRule
{
    public bool IsValid(string value)
    {
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) || 
               (value.Length == 10 && 
               !value.AsEnumerable().Any (t => !char.IsDigit(t)));
    }
}
```

This code conforms to your requirement where you say that a NULL (or empty) string should be considered valid albeit I am a bit perplexed by this condition. However it is easy to change that part using

```
 return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) && ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `long.TryParse`.

```
public bool IsValid(string value)
{
    long temp;
    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) || (value.Length == 10 && long.TryParse(string, out temp));
}
```

Edit: other people are right; use `long.TryParse()`. `int` overflows at `2147483648`, which will not give you the full range of 10 digit numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```
public bool IsValid(string value)
{
    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) || value.Length == 10 && Regex.IsMatch(value, @"^[0-9]+$");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public bool IsValid(string value)
{  
    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) || value.ToArray<char>().All<char>(i=>char.IsDigit(i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I got the point... to check if a string represent a number you can try to convert it into Integer or Double (if the case)

```
   int n = 0;
   if (Int32.TryParse(value, out n))
   {
   }
```

HTH,
Cabbi

Answer (score 0):

use regex

```
public bool IsValid(string value)
{
    return Regex.IsMatch(value, @"^[0-9]{10}$");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Per your specification:

```
public static bool IsValid(string value)
{
    return value == null || (value.Length == 10 && value.All(Char.IsDigit));
}
```